# Using Spring Boot WebClient to call a dummy api to postman

Tags: spring-boot, httprequest, spring-webflux, webclient, dummy-data

I am missing something here. I am attempting to pull information using Spring Boot WebClient from a Dummy Api that's an Http request. I am not getting any info pulled when I go into postman.

Thanks for any insight you can give me. I am still very new to coding and self-taught.

Here's my employee controller:

```java
@Autowired
WebClientApp webClientApp;

@GetMapping("/consume")
public String getEmployee(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("listEmployees", empServiceImpl.getAllEmployees());
  model.addAttribute("listemps", webClientApp.webClientBuilder());
  return "index";
}
```

Web Client

```java
private WebClient webClient;

public  void SimpleWebClient(WebClient webClient) {
  this.webClient = webClient;
}

public Flux<Employee> webClientBuilder() {
  
  return this.webClient
  //this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder.baseUrl(DummyEmployee)
    .get()
    .uri("api/v1/employees")
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(Employee.class);
}
```

Employee

```java
@Data
@ToString
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonRootName(value = "data")
public class Employee {

  @JsonProperty("id")   
  public int employeeID;
  @JsonProperty("employee_name")
  public String employeeName;
  @JsonProperty("employee_salary")
  public String employeeSalary;
  @JsonProperty("employee_age")
  public int employeeAge;
  @JsonProperty("employee_image")
  public Blob employeeImage;
}
```

Service

```java
@Repository
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.app.repository"})
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements EmpService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
      return (List<Employee>) employeeRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Service

```java
@Service
public interface EmpService {
  
    static List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
}
```

Main

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(RestWebsiteDataProjectApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public WebClient  webClientFromScratch() {
  return WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/")   
    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Flux` only emits its content when it is subscribed. You are not subscribing to the `Flux` returned by the `webClientBuilder()` method.
You shouldn't really do this, but try adding `.block()` to your Controller as follows:

```java
@Autowired
WebClientApp webClientApp;

@GetMapping("/consume")
public String getEmployee(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("listEmployees", empServiceImpl.getAllEmployees());
  model.addAttribute("listemps", webClientApp.webClientBuilder().block());
  return "index";
}
```

If this works, please consider reworking your code because while working with Spring WebFlux (reactive programming) you should always deal with `Mono` and `Flux` so that you can take full advantage of the reactive stack.

Comment: Dias Tried adding .block() but no go. When I first wrote it out, I tried to use Flux<Employee> but Eclipse threw up errors and gave suggestions to go to string. I originally thought the same with Flux.  Not sure how to go about it without it throwing up errors again. I use flux in my web client. Which other spot specifically should I rewrite to use flux?

Comment: Not really sure to be honest, because you are mixing Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux and I am not entirely sure that this is possible.